# Wordpress showing two menus

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

On my website (www.peoplesarms.com) home page everything is fine.  What I can't figure out is that when I go to *Contact Us*, *Cart*, *My Account*, potentially *Checkout* though it shows the same screen as cart at the moment because no shop items there yet,  there is an extra (not useful) menu showing `HOME >> CART` or `HOME >> CONTACT US`

I want to get rid of that, but I can't seem to figure out where that is coming from.
All I want there to be is the main menu right under the logo.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in this case the breadcrumbs was coming from the theme.  Not sure why it did it that way, but they did.  The solution was to alter the css to display: none; on #breadcrumbs id's.  The reason it didn't appear to be working was because the hosting service had turned on the cached pages function and wasn't serving the altered css file.  I banged my head on that for about 2 hours trying for all my ability to understand why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

It is known as **breadcrumbs**. You are using *online-store* theme with *kirki* customizer plugin with comes up with an option to enable/disable it from backend.

To disable to go to

> Appearance > Customize > WooCommerce > Breadcrumbs(uncheck the button)

[image: Check the screenshot for details]

It should have worked but what I saw maxstore theme does not care about the above steps so you can fallow any of the below methord.

**Method 1: Modify the function**

Removed all the code inside the function present in `wp-content\themes\maxstore\functions.php`

```
function maxstore_breadcrumb() {
    return '';
}
```

**Method 2: Comment out the function from template files**

You need to comment out `maxstore_breadcrumb();` from the below listed 4 PHP file in *maxstore* theme.

1. wp-content\themes\maxstore\archive.php
2. wp-content\themes\maxstore\content-page.php
3. wp-content\themes\maxstore\content-single.php
4. wp-content\themes\maxstore\index.php

Please Note: If you 'll upgrade the theme you might have to follow this steps again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay the strange thing is that is already disabled. slider is right and grey.  Yet some pages are still doing it.

Comment: I tried putting the code in multiple places to no effect.  I am thinking I might have to recreate all of the pages with it disabled to get it to not work in this case

Comment: AH, I think it is using its own breadcrumbs and not woocommerce.

maxstore_breadcrumb is a function in the master template functions.

Comment: I can't figure out how to disable the one from the maxstore theme yet.